# PMU for multi threaded environment

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, intel

I am planning to measure PMU counters for L1,L2,L3 misses branch prediction misses , I have read related Intel documents but i am unsure about the below scenarios.could some one please clarify ?

```
//assume PMU reset and PERFEVTSELx configurtion done above 
ioctl(fd, IOCTL_MSR_CMDS, (long long)msr_start)  //PMU start counters
my_program();
ioctl(fd, IOCTL_MSR_CMDS, (long long)msr_stop)   ///PMU stop
//now reading PMU counters
```

1.what will happen if my process is scheduled out when my_program() is running, and scheduled to another core?

2.what will happen if process scheduled out and schedule back to same core again, meanwhile some other process reset the PMU counters?

How to make sure that we are reading the correct values from PMU counters.?

> Machine details:CentOS with Linux kernel 3.10.0-327.22.2.el7.x86_64 , which is powered up with Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz

Thanks

Comment: You *do* realize that `perf` can read the hardware performance counters for you?

Comment: yes, i read perf documents. It will not much helpful for my app, it has lot of restriction/linux dependencies which we dont want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the answers from some Intel forum, the link is below.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-moderncode-for-parallel-architectures/topic/673602

Comment: I posted a proper answer with some quotes from that thread.  Thanks for linking the thread where the answers are, but SO standards require at least a summary of links, because link-only answers become useless when the link breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Summary of [the Intel forum thread](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-moderncode-for-parallel-architectures/topic/673602) started by the OP:

- The Linux `perf` subsystem virtualizes the performance counters, but this means you have to read them with a system call, instead of `rdpmc`, to get the full virtualized 64-bit value instead of whatever is currently in the architectural performance counter register.
- If you want to use `rdpmc` inside your own code so it can measure itself, pin each thread to a core because context switches don't save/restore PMCs.  There's no easy way to avoid measuring *everything* that happens on the core, including interrupt handlers and other processes that get a timeslice.  This can be a good thing, since you need to take the impact of kernel overhead into account.

---

More useful quotes from John D. McCalpin, PhD ("Dr. Bandwidth"):

> For inline code instrumentation you should be able to use the "perf events" API, but the documentation is minimal.  Some resources are available at [http://web.eece.maine.edu/~vweaver/projects/perf_events/faq.html](http://web.eece.maine.edu/%7Evweaver/projects/perf_events/faq.html)
>
> You can use "pread()" on the /dev/cpu/*/msr device files to read the
> MSRs -- this may be a bit easier to read than IOCTL-based code.  The
> codes "rdmsr.c" and "wrmsr.c" from "msr-tools-1.3" provide excellent
> examples.

> There have been a number of approaches to reserving and sharing
> performance counters, including both software-only and combined
> hardware+software approaches, but at this point there is not a
> "standard" approach.  (It looks like Intel has a hardware-based
> approach using MSR 0x392 IA32_PERF_GLOBAL_INUSE, but I don't know what
> platforms support it.)

---

**your questions**

> what will happen if my process is scheduled out when my_program() is running, and scheduled to another core?

You'll see random garbage, same if another process resets PMCs between timeslices of your process.

Comment: yes. To avoid this we can use thread affinity , but still this will also not give exact outputs/counts, even some times this values also junk.As for, i understand we cannot get exact PMU counter values with multi threaded environment without taking proper precaution and/or in-depth OS scheduler knowledge.