# How to use CPUID as a serializing instruction?

Tags: c++, assembly, cpuid

CPUID can be used as a serializing instruction as described [here](https://xem.github.io/minix86/manual/intel-x86-and-64-manual-vol3/o_fe12b1e2a880e0ce-273.html) and [here](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/ia-32-ia-64-benchmark-code-execution-paper.pdf). What is the minimal/simplest asm syntax to use it in that way in C++?

```
// Is that enough?
// What to do with registers and memory?
// Is volatile necessary?
asm volatile("CPUID":::);
```

Comment: Technically, you can't do it at all since inline assembly is a compiler-specific thing that doesn't exist in standard C++. While we could *guess* which compiler you're most likely using, always include that information when asking questions about inline assembly. Also mentioning target ISA is usually a good idea, even it if also can be guessed in this case.

Comment: Use a builtin instead of asm. `cpuid` overwrites registers, at the very least you need to list `eax`,`ebx`,`ecx` and `edx` as clobbers. Yes, `volatile` is necessary.

Comment: `#include <intrin.h>` and use the `__cpuid()` function.

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: If you need to serialize `rdtsc`, use `lfence`.  It's guaranteed by Intel to work (at least on Intel CPUs).  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38994549/is-intels-timestamp-reading-asm-code-example-using-two-more-registers-than-are.  (However, [on AMD it seems you need `mfence` instead of `lfence`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12631856/difference-between-rdtscp-rdtsc-memory-and-cpuid-rdtsc#comment84001167_12634857), so `cpuid` is apparently more portable)

Comment: Related: [Using inline assembly with serialization instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48522628) / [Is there a cheaper serializing instruction than cpuid?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75456027) - only `cpuid` (or the very recent `serialize`) are fully serializing, usable for cross-modifying code.  `lfence` or `mfence;lfence` will drain the ROB, or store-buffer+ROB, before later instructions which is all you need if you aren't doing cross-modifying code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you're not using the fence operations? If the goal is to serialize a section of code you can do something like

```
 asm __volatile__ (
      " mfence \n"   // drain the store buffer
      " lfence \n"   // and wait for that instruction to retire, draining the ROB
      ::: "memory"); // block compile-time reordering.
Your code here
  asm __volatile__ (
      " mfence \n"
      " lfence \n"
      ::: "memory" );
```

This is about as much serialization as you get from `cpuid` in terms of memory and instruction reordering.  But neither is officially a Serializing Instruction in Intel's technical terminology.

Software prefetches aren't guaranteed to be ordered wrt. fence instructions, so on paper at least, an earlier [`prefetcht0`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/prefetchh) could result in data arriving after the `lfence`.  (But a `prefetcht0` *after* an `lfence` can't execute until after the `lfence` finishes, because no instructions after an `lfence` get sent to execution units until all instructions earlier have retired.  "completed locally" in [Intel's documentation](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/lfence).)

`lfence` blocking instruction reordering is how Intel CPUs always work, but AMD only with an MSR setting.  OSes that do Spectre mitigation set that MSR: [Is LFENCE serializing on AMD processors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51844886/is-lfence-serializing-on-amd-processors)

Comment: The intel manual says: _"MFENCE does not serialize the instruction stream."_

Comment: "Perform a serializing operation on all load-from-memory and store-to-memory instructions that were issued prior to this instruction. Guarantees that every memory access that precedes, in program order, the memory fence instruction is globally visible before any memory instruction which follows the fence in program order."

https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=fence&expand=3424

Comment: Yes, but that only deals with memory operations. _"Non-privileged serializing instructions -- CPUID, IRET, and RSM._" and _"The following instructions are memory-ordering instructions, not serializing instructions. These drain the data memory subsystem. They do not serialize the instruction execution stream.  Non-privileged memory-ordering instructions -- SFENCE, LFENCE, and MFENCE."_

Comment: @Jester: `lfence` is now (or will be) officially documented as serializing, following years of that being an implementation detail, but still seeing some Intel docs recommend or at least use `lfence; rdtsc`.  At least *some* good came out of Spectre...  (I'm not 100% sure it's as strongly serializing as `cpuid`, though).  But anyway, you're right that `mfence` isn't serializing on the instruction stream, on paper or in practice.  Using both `lfence` and `mfence` back to back  doesn't seem useful.

Comment: Correction: `lfence` is serializing *on the instruction stream*, without flushing the store buffer.  It's sufficient for `lfence; rdtsc`.  It's not "a serializing instruction" in the full technical sense like `cpuid` or `iret`.  And `mfence` is serializing on AMD according to documentation, and in practice also on some Intel CPUs like Skylake, possibly a microcode update to fix an erratum strengthened it to be much stronger than the Intel manual guarantees:  [Are loads and stores the only instructions that gets reordered?](//stackoverflow.com/a/50496379)

Comment: And also: [Is LFENCE serializing on AMD processors?](//stackoverflow.com/q/51844886)  yes, with Spectre mitigation active the relevant MSR will be set so LFENCE blocks speculative execution like on Intel.

Comment: Anyway, you forgot `"memory"` clobbers, so compile-time reordering of code into / out of the serialized block is still possible.