# Using inline assembly with serialization instructions

Tags: c++, gcc, x86, inline-assembly, cpuid

We consider that we are using `GCC` (or `GCC`-compatible) compiler on a `X86_64` architecture, and that `eax`, `ebx`, `ecx`, `edx` and `level` are variables (`unsigned int` or `unsigned int*`) for input and output of the instruction (like [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/config/i386/cpuid.h)).

```
asm("CPUID":::);
asm volatile("CPUID":::);
asm volatile("CPUID":::"memory");
asm volatile("CPUID":"=a"(eax),"=b"(ebx),"=c"(ecx),"=d"(edx)::"memory");
asm volatile("CPUID":"=a"(eax):"0"(level):"memory");
asm volatile("CPUID"::"a"(level):"memory"); // Not sure of this syntax
asm volatile("CPUID":"=a"(eax),"=b"(ebx),"=c"(ecx),"=d"(edx):"0"(level):"memory");
asm("CPUID":"=a"(eax),"=b"(ebx),"=c"(ecx),"=d"(edx):"0"(level):"memory");
asm volatile("CPUID":"=a"(eax),"=b"(ebx),"=c"(ecx),"=d"(edx):"0"(level));
```

- I am not used to the inline assembly syntax, and I am wondering what would be the difference between all these calls, in a context where I just want to use `CPUID` as a [serializing instruction](https://xem.github.io/minix86/manual/intel-x86-and-64-manual-vol3/o_fe12b1e2a880e0ce-273.html) (e.g. nothing will be done with the output of the instruction).
- Can some of these calls lead to errors?
- Which one(s) of these calls would be the most suited (given that I want the least overhead as possible, but at the same time the "strongest" serialization possible)?

Comment: What you want to achieve by serializing ? Your list of inline `asm` is like randomly picked up. All those output looks strange if you don't need the cpuid information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `lfence` may be strongly serializing enough for your use-case, e.g. for `rdtsc`.  If you care about performance, check and see if you can find evidence that `lfence` is strong enough (at least for your use-case).  Possibly even [using both `mfence; lfence`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48502569/how-to-use-cpuid-as-a-serializing-instruction#comment84000421_48502710) might be better than `cpuid`, if you want to e.g. drain the store buffer before an `rdtsc`.

But neither `lfence` nor `mfence` are serializing on the whole pipeline in the official technical-terminology meaning, which [could matter for cross-modifying code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280697/is-there-a-cheaper-serializing-instruction-than-cpuid/75456027#75456027) - discarding instructions that might have been fetched before some stores from another core became visible.

---

2. Yes, all the ones that don't tell the compiler that the asm statement writes E[A-D]X are dangerous and will likely cause hard-to-debug weirdness.  (i.e. you need to use (dummy) output operands or clobbers).

You need `volatile`, because you want the asm code to be executed for the side-effect of serialization, not to produce the outputs.

If you don't want to use the CPUID result for anything (e.g. do double duty by serializing *and* querying something), you should simply list the registers as clobbers, not outputs, so you don't need any C variables to hold the results.

```
// volatile is already implied because there are no output operands
// but it doesn't hurt to be explicit.

// Serialize and block compile-time reordering of loads/stores across this
asm volatile("CPUID"::: "eax","ebx","ecx","edx", "memory");

// the "eax" clobber covers RAX in x86-64 code, you don't need an #ifdef __i386__
```

> I am wondering what would be the difference between all these calls

First of all, none of these are "calls".  They're asm *statements*, and inline into the function where you use them.  CPUID itself is not a "call" either, although I guess you could look at it as calling a microcode function built-in to the CPU.  But by that logic, every instruction is a "call", e.g. `mul rcx` takes inputs in RAX and RCX, and returns in RDX:RAX.

---

The first three (and the later one with no outputs, just a `level` input) destroy RAX through RDX without telling the compiler.  It will assume that those registers still hold whatever it was keeping in them.  They're obviously unusable.

---

`asm("CPUID":"=a"(eax),"=b"(ebx),"=c"(ecx),"=d"(edx):"0"(level):"memory");` (**the one without `volatile`) will optimize away if you don't use any of the outputs**.  And if you do use them, it can still be hoisted out of loops.  A non-`volatile` asm statement is treated by the optimizer as a pure function with no side effects.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#index-asm-volatile

It has a memory clobber, but (I think) that doesn't stop it from optimizing away, it just means that if / when / where it *does* run, any variables it could possibly read / write are synced to memory, so memory contents match what the C abstract machine would have at that point.  This may exclude locals that haven't had their address taken, though.

`asm("" ::: "memory")` is very similar to `std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_seq_cst)`, but note that that `asm` statement has no outputs, and thus is implicitly `volatile`.  *That's* why it isn't optimized away, not because of the `"memory"` clobber itself.  **A (`volatile`) asm statement with a memory clobber is a compiler barrier against reordering loads or stores across it.**

The optimizer doesn't care at all what's inside the first string literal, only the constraints / clobbers, so `asm volatile("anything" ::: register clobbers, "memory")` is also a compile-time-only memory barrier.  I assume this is what you want, to serialize some memory operations.

---

`"0"(level)` is a matching constraint for the first operand (the `"=a"`).  You could equally have written `"a"(level)`, because in this case the compiler doesn't have a choice of which register to select; the output constraint can only be satisfied by `eax`.  You could also have used `"+a"(eax)` as the output operand, but then you'd have to set `eax=level` before the asm statement.  Matching constraints instead of read-write operands are sometimes necessary for x87 stack stuff; I think that came up once in an SO question.  But other than weird stuff like that, the advantage is being able to use different C variables for input and output, or not using a variable at all for the input.  (e.g. a literal constant, or an lvalue (expression)).

Anyway, telling the compiler to provide an input will probably result in an extra instruction, e.g. `level=0` would result in an `xor`-zeroing of `eax`.  This would be a waste of an instruction if it didn't already need a zeroed register for anything earlier.  Normally xor-zeroing an input would break a dependency on the previous value, but the whole point of CPUID here is that it's *serializing*, so it has to wait for all previous instructions to finish executing anyway.  Making sure `eax` is ready early is pointless; **if you don't care about the outputs, don't even tell the compiler your asm statement takes an input**.  Compilers make it difficult or impossible to use an undefined / uninitialized value with no overhead; sometimes leaving a C variable uninitialized will result in loading garbage from the stack, or zeroing a register, instead of just using a register without writing it first.

Comment: I'm just curious, from the viewpoint of a user-land program, is there anything that only `CPUID` can achieve but not memory order?

Comment: @liliscent: Yes, `rdtsc` was the classic example.  If you want to make sure `rdtsc` doesn't sample the clock before previous instructions have completed (including ALU instructions), you need a barrier on the *instruction stream*, not data loads/stores.  So `cpuid; rdtsc` is a common idiom.  However, `lfence;rdtsc` works too, at least on Intel, because `lfence` is implemented as a serializing instruction.  With no NT loads / stores in flight, `lfence` is (was) architecturally a no-op, but *micro*architecturally it's serializing.  `mfence` may not work, even though it's a stronger mem barrier.

Comment: @liliscent: Spectre v1 (bounds-check bypass) mitigation is another recent example.  So important that it led Intel to document `lfence` as serializing the instruction stream, and thus blocking speculative execution past previous branches.   Intel whitepapers and sample code did use `lfence ; rdtsc`, but it was hard to find out *why* that was valid, because [the insn ref manual entry for `lfence`](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/LFENCE) doesn't (currently) mention anything about serializing instructions, only memory operations.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12631856/difference-between-rdtscp-rdtsc-memory-and-cpuid-rdtsc.  `mfence` is serializing on AMD (and `lfence` maybe isn't; it has 4 per clock throughput on Bulldozer/Ryzen...)  And newer CPUs support `rdtscp` which has a built-in one-way barrier.  There's a link in [this old answer I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39002894/224132) with some older (pre Spectre) details about LFENCE serializing RDTSC.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation !

Comment: @liliscent: I was trying to figure out if you were asking about the `lfence` *instruction*, or really just the memory-ordering effect of instructions like `lfence` and `mfence` :P  It's complicated because of memory-ordering instructions also having serializing effects on some CPUs...  (And I'm not 100% sure that `lfence` is as strongly serializing as `cpuid`, or about mfence vs. lfence on AMD vs. Intel; that would probably make a good question.)

Comment: @llllllllll: Update: a true serializing instruction can matter for stale code-fetch in cross-modifying code.  My previous comments were wildly optimistic about `lfence`; it doesn't even wait for the store-buffer to drain.  It only serializes instruction execution (drain the ROB before dispatch of any instruction after `lfence`).  I updated my answer, linking [Is there a cheaper serializing instruction than cpuid?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75456027) for more details.