# Clobbered memory in two inline assembly calls vs in one inline assembly call?

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly, cpuid

This question follows this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48522628/using-inline-assembly-with-serialization-instructions), considering a `GCC`-compliant compiler and a `x86-64` architecture.

I am wondering if there is any difference between `option 1`, `option 2` and `option 3` below. Would the result be the same in all contexts, or would it be different. And if so what would be the difference?

```
// Option 1
asm volatile(:::"memory");
asm volatile("CPUID":"=a"(eax),"=b"(ebx),"=c"(ecx),"=d"(edx):"0"(level):);
```

and

```
// Option 2
asm volatile("CPUID":"=a"(eax),"=b"(ebx),"=c"(ecx),"=d"(edx):"0"(level):);
asm volatile(:::"memory");
```

and

```
// Option 3
asm volatile("CPUID":"=a"(eax),"=b"(ebx),"=c"(ecx),"=d"(edx):"0"(level):"memory");
```

Comment: 2&3 should be the same. 1 would force reload of `level` from memory, if it happens to be there.

Comment: @Jester: option 2 would let the CPUID itself reorder with unrelated non-`volatile` loads/stores.  This is very likely *not* what you want.

Comment: @Jester: actually only reloaded if it's address has escaped the function, or something like that.  It doesn't force a reload if it was in memory as a stack arg, or a normal local spilled due to register pressure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Options 1 & 2 would let the CPUID itself reorder with unrelated non-`volatile` loads/stores (in one direction or the other).  This is very likely *not* what you want.

You could put a memory barrier on *both* sides of CPUID, but it's certainly better to just make CPUID a memory barrier itself.

---

As Jester points out, option 1 would force reload of `level` from memory, if it had ever had its address passed outside of the function, or if it already *is* a global or `static`.

(Or whatever the exact criterion is that decides whether a C variable could be modified read or written by asm that uses a `"memory"` clobber.  I think it's essentially the same as what the optimizer uses to decide whether a variable can be kept in a register across a non-inline function call to an opaque function, so pure local variables that haven't had their address passed anywhere, and that aren't inputs to the asm statement, can still live in registers).

For example ([Godbolt compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'void+cpuid1(int+level)%7B%0A++++int+eax,+ebx,+ecx,+edx%3B%0A++++asm+volatile(%22%22:::%22memory%22)%3B%0A++++asm+volatile(%22CPUID%22%0A++++:++%22%3Da%22(eax),%22%3Db%22(ebx),%22%3Dc%22(ecx),%22%3Dd%22(edx)%0A++++:++%220%22(level):)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0Avoid+modify_level(int+level)%7B%0A++++level+%2B%3D+1%3B%0A++++int+eax,+ebx,+ecx,+edx%3B%0A++++asm+volatile(%22%23mem+barrier+here%22:::%22memory%22)%3B%0A++++asm+volatile(%22CPUID%22%0A++++:++%22%3Da%22(eax),%22%3Db%22(ebx),%22%3Dc%22(ecx),%22%3Dd%22(edx)%0A++++:++%220%22(level):)%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:40.67076742823668,l:'4',m:56.16883116883117,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+7.3',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:43.83116883116883,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:40.67076742823668,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g73,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-fverbose-asm',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+7.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:27.260961606590858,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g73,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-fverbose-asm+-m32',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+7.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:32.068270965172466,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',m:100,n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)):

```
void foo(int level){
    int eax, ebx, ecx, edx;
    asm volatile("":::"memory");
    asm volatile("CPUID"
        :  "=a"(eax),"=b"(ebx),"=c"(ecx),"=d"(edx)
        :  "0"(level)
        :
    );
}

# x86-64 gcc7.3  -O3 -fverbose-asm

    pushq   %rbx  #           # rbx is call-preserved, but we clobber it.
    movl    %edi, %eax      # level, eax
    CPUID
    popq    %rbx    #
    ret
```

Notice the lack of a spill/reload of the function arg.

Normally I'd use Intel syntax, but with inline asm it's a good idea to always use AT&T unless you complete hate AT&T syntax or don't know it.

Even if it started in memory (i386 System V calling convention, with stack args), the compiler still decides that nothing else (including the `asm` statement with a memory clobber) could reference it.  But how do we tell the difference between delaying the load?  Modify the function arg before the barrier, then use it after:

```
void modify_level(int level){
    level += 1;                  // modify level before the barrier
    int eax, ebx, ecx, edx;
    asm volatile("#mem barrier here":::"memory");
    asm volatile("CPUID"         // then read it after
    :  "=a"(eax),"=b"(ebx),"=c"(ecx),"=d"(edx)
    :  "0"(level):);
}
```

The asm output from `gcc -m32 -O3 -fverbose-asm` is:

```
modify_level(int):
    pushl   %ebx  #
    #mem barrier here
    movl    8(%esp), %eax   # level, tmp97
    addl    $1, %eax        #, level
    CPUID
    popl    %ebx    #
    ret
```

Notice that the compiler let `level++` reorder across the memory barrier, because it's a local variable.

Godbolt filters hand-written asm comments along with compiler-generated asm comment-only lines.  I disabled the comment filter and found the mem barrier.  You might want to remove -fverbose-asm to get less noise.  Or use a non-comment string for the mem barrier: it doesn't have to assemble if you're just looking at the compiler's asm output.  (Unless you're using clang, which has the assembler built-in).

---

BTW, the original version of your question didn't compile: you left out the empty string as asm template.  `asm(:::"memory")`.  The output, input, and clobber sections can be empty, but the asm instruction string is not optional.

Fun fact, you can put asm comments in the string:

```
asm volatile("# memory barrier here":::"memory");
```

gcc fills in any `%whatever` things in the string template as it writes asm output, so you can even do stuff like `"CPUID  # %%0 was in %0"` and see what gcc chose for your "dummy" args that are otherwise unmentioned in the asm template.  (This is more interesting for dummy memory input/output operands to tell the compiler which memory you read/write instead of using a `"memory"` clobber, when you give the asm statement a pointer.)

Comment: "Normally I'd use Intel syntax" - unless you are creating a header for a library, then consider using [dialects](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Multiple-assembler-dialects-in-asm-templates).  The idea being that as a header, you cannot know whether the file you are being included into is being built with `-masm=intel` or `att`.